# How to stop note to stop auto convert double qoute to inverted comma?

Tags: macos, notes.app

This is the text I want to keep in a note:

```
gcloud compute --project "wordpress-test" instance-groups unmanaged create "instance-group-wordpress" --zone "us-central1-b"
```

However note will always automatically convert the last double quote to a "smart inverted comma" like so:

```
gcloud compute --project "wordpress-test" instance-groups unmanaged create "instance-group-wordpress" --zone "us-central1-b”
```

[image]

(You have to manually type it in order to trigger this behavior)

Is there any way I can stop this conversion?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Right-click inside your note, then uncheck the following option:

[image: Smart Quotes Substitutions]

**Notes** will no longer replace your smart quotes. Unfortunately, this applies to all notes. I don’t think there is a way to restrict this setting to a single Note.

Comment: That's good enough for me. I am happy to have it turned off for all notes

Comment: Since many years I was stuck with this. Finally thought of looking up and you are a saviour!